# Kiosk mode in Android at runtime

Tags: android, kiosk

Setting any application in Kiosk mode in run time and maintaining its state even after switching off the device in android.

We have created an application which display the list of all the installed application in the android. We select few of the application to run in kiosk mode. Now we want that even after restarting the device, application should be in kiosk mode.

But it is not happening in my case.

Kindly help us

Answer (score 2):

I have Completed Kiosk mode in Android. I have two methods to handle this scenario

1.)Make your application as home launcher so it gets loaded whenever you restart the device.

2)If you dont want to make it as launcher, Then create a broadcast receiver with Boot_Completed receiver and start your application from it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually we have done like that only. Now in this application , we are displaying all teh application installed in the android mobile in a list.

Comment: We want that as we select the installed application , only those application can be run in kiosk mode. Now when we restart the device, again I have to select the those application. I want to avoid this and it should show previously selected application

Comment: Use an activity without layout after u select the application from list to start by passing component values of selected application. Later when u restart, call this activity. so use any method to store the component values and again start the same app.

Comment: In Android 4.x making an app a home launcher doesn't lock it down, you can still get to the settings menu by pulling down the notification bar. This obviously fails when it comes to kiosk mode!

Comment: You can collapse the Notification bar.. So that u cant even drag the notification bar..

Comment: Jai, how do you do this?

Comment: public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
        try
        {
           if(!hasFocus)
           {
                Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                collapse .setAccessible(true);
                collapse .invoke(service);
           }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
}

Comment: @JaiKumar, can you share your source code regarding this? I badly need to finish my project. :(

Comment: No, Sorry. I cant do it.